# TypeScript with React Redux, connect type

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, typescript-typings

I have a HOC that is connected to redux like this way:

```
const withSignIn = (WrappedComponent: React.FC<WithSignInProps>) => {
  const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }: AuthRootState) => ({
    error: auth.error,
    loading: auth.loading
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    signIn
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrappedComponent);
};

export default withSignIn;
```

I'm missing return type on function `withSignIn` but I don't know what type should I cast my function, it's returning a `connect()` function there, any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking is there https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component

to be more accurate this lines

```
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

// The inferred type will look like:
// {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
  backgroundColor: string
}
```

So I guess what you return is

```
React.FC<WithSignInProps & PropsFromRedux>
```

I didn't have enough code to try it myself, tell me if it works for you :)